# d3 selectAll and accesing item with index gives different result

Tags: d3.js

when i do selectAll and expand the returned array it shows one result as below

```
prevchart.selectAll(".line")
```

result in console shows

```
[Array[1]0: pathlength: 1parentNode: g__proto__: Array[0]
```

but when i do `prevchart.selectAll(".line")[0]` it just retun matching dom element as below `<path class="line" d="M20,46.753246753246756L152,37.40259740259741L284,28.051948051948052L416,9.350649350649356L548,0L680,18.701298701298704"></path>`

if you notice that selectAll return different result with javascript object and using the index in array returns a dom element.

I have attached image to make it more clear[image]

why is it behaving like this.

what i would need to do to get that javascript object on which i can do other operations.

Comment: Because D3 selections aren't arrays and you shouldn't treat them as such.

Comment: A selection is an array of groups, a group is an array of nodes. Some of the nodes may be null and some may be place holder objects with a `__data__` member (if it's the enter selection), the reast are DOM elements.  The array of groups has extra behaviours added by the selection prototype and a `__data__` member, the groups have a parent node member added. Both inherit full array behaviour from the built in Array prototype. Other members are added as required, to store information and callbacks for transitions for example, but they are still 2-D arrays.

Comment: @CoolBlue: Isn't that an *answer*?

Comment: @Mars To be honest, I don't really understand the question so I'm not sure if it is an answer or not.  Anyway, there are some small errors so I'll post a corrected version as an answer...

Comment: i have added the image to explain it more clearly..i want to get that javascript object of first element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is not clear to me but I think its an important topic.

- A selection is an array of groups
- a group is an array of nodes. Some of the nodes may be null and some may be place holder objects with a `__data__` member (if it's the enter selection), the rest are DOM elements which also have a `__data__` member added.  A member with a reference to the group parent node is also added on each group.
- The array of groups has extra behaviour added by the selection prototype
- Both dimensions inherit full array behaviour from the built in Array prototype. Other members are added as required, to store information and callbacks for transitions for example, but selections are still 2-D arrays.

EDIT: I think this is what you are trying to do...

```
var lineCharts = prevchart.selectAll(".lineChart")
.attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
   return "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (currentYAxisHeight * i) + ")"
})
```

Comment: this isnt explain why accessing with index returns dom element.

Comment: It's not a DOM element, it's an array of DOM elements of length 1. You can see this from your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this the correct approach but i did following and it helped me to achieve what i wanted.

i first got the element using selectAll, then used select to apply attr on each element.

```
var lineCharts =  prevchart.selectAll(".lineChart");
for (var i = 0; i < noOfLineChart; i++) {
var chart = d3.select(linecharts[0][i]);
chart.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (currentYAxisHeight * i) + ")"); 
}
```

Comment: Can you include your html?

Comment: That works because the object you are asking about is an array, not a DOM element as you claim. But you don't need the loop, d3 will handle that for you. See the edit in my answer.